# java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: java, android, feed, java-io

I am currently working on someone else's project as they have left the company. 
I am only on a internship and java isn't my strong subject.

Basically the application works from receiving the information from a feed and places that information in the relevant places.

However the client as asked for a graphic to be place on the images which have the let agreed.

This is has been done for me as i don't have any accesses to the feed.

I would like to point out that the feed with the graphic is working perfectly fine on the iPhone app.

Upon pressing the search button this message prints out in my log cat:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://images.ultrait.me/ImageProcessor.aspx?imageURL=381/Sales/321470/53659_T_ADDRESSES_52050_TN.jpg&Text=LET AGREED

As you can see from clicking the link the icon appears.

When i click on to the tab to search for properties the feed will begin to load, and the images will appear in a list view. The images will appear but it doesn't have the let agreed icon on it, i believe it is because it is placing image one from the feed as the thumbnail, but i need it to display the graphic(I'm not sure if this is even correct).

When i click to view a property the image disappears.

I am working to a deadline and i have noone to help me out.  Please be patient with me.

Here are some of my classes which i think you might need to see.

```
public class _06_Photos extends Activity implements ViewFactory{

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;


    //GUI  Components
    TextView tv_counter;
    //ImageView iv_activity;
    ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher;

    Button b_play;
    Button b_next;
    Button b_previous;

    FrameLayout topFrame, bottomFrame;


    //Images and Stuff
    String [] str_imageURLs;
    Bitmap [] bm_images;
    int picNum = 0;
    boolean play;
    boolean stop;
    Handler handler;

    Thread playThread;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.xl_06_photos);

        handler = new Handler();

        playThread = new Thread(Play);

        play = false;
        stop = false;
        playThread.start();

        str_imageURLs = new String[5];
        for(int i=0; i<5;++i)
            str_imageURLs[i] = "";

        bm_images = new Bitmap[5];

        InitView();

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            str_imageURLs[0] = extras.getString("img1");
            str_imageURLs[1] = extras.getString("img2");
            str_imageURLs[2] = extras.getString("img3");
            str_imageURLs[3] = extras.getString("img4");
            str_imageURLs[4] = extras.getString("img5");
        }

        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
            System.out.println(str_imageURLs[i]);


        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
                {
                    try{
                        bm_images[i] = FindPropertyActivity.DownloadImage(str_imageURLs[i]);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println("Image" + i + " not downloaded - " + e);
                    }

                    try{
                    if(bm_images[i] == null)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Bitmap " + i + " is null");
                        bm_images[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.download_error);
                    }

                    if(picNum == i)
                        //iv_activity.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        //Drawable d =new BitmapDrawable(bm_images[i]);
                        //imageSwitcher.setImageDrawable(d);
                        handler.post(SetPic);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println("PicNum null/visiablity" + i + " not setCorrectly - " + e);
                    }
                }
                System.gc();
            }
          }).start();
    }

    private void InitView(){

        handler.post(SetPic);
        tv_counter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.photo_tv_counter);
        imageSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.photo_imageSwitcher);
        imageSwitcher.setFactory(this);

        topFrame = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.photo_topFrame);
        bottomFrame = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.photo_bottomFrame);


        final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
        imageSwitcher.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                    return true;
            }
        });

        b_play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.photo_b_play);
        if(play){   
            b_play.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_pause));
            topFrame.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bottomFrame.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            b_play.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_play)); 

        }
        b_play.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Drawable background =  v.getBackground();
                    background.setColorFilter(0xFF7A7A7A, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                    v.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    Drawable background =  v.getBackground();
                    background.setColorFilter(null);
                    v.setBackgroundDrawable(background);

                    if(play){
                        play = false;
                        b_play.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_play));
                    }

                    else{
                        play = true;
                        b_play.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_pause));
                        topFrame.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        bottomFrame.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });



        b_previous = (Button)findViewById(R.id.photo_b_previous);
        b_previous.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Drawable background =  v.getBackground();
                    background.setColorFilter(0xFF7A7A7A, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                    v.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    Drawable background =  v.getBackground();
                    background.setColorFilter(null);
                    v.setBackgroundDrawable(background);

                    PreviousPic();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        b_next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.photo_b_next);
        b_next.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Drawable background =  v.getBackground();
                    background.setColorFilter(0xFF7A7A7A, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                    v.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    Drawable background =  v.getBackground();
                    background.setColorFilter(null);
                    v.setBackgroundDrawable(background);

                    NextPic();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        stop = true;
    }

    private final Runnable SetPic = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //iv_activity.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Drawable d =new BitmapDrawable(bm_images[picNum]);
            imageSwitcher.setImageDrawable(d);
            System.out.println("Pic Set");

            tv_counter.setText("" + (picNum+1) + "/5");
        }
    };

    private final Runnable Play = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while(!stop){
                try{

                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            if(play)
                                NextPic();
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Play Error - " + e);
                }
            }
        }
    };


    protected void NextPic(){

        try{
            picNum++;
            if(picNum > 4)
                picNum = 0;

            tv_counter.setText("" + (picNum+1) + "/5");

            imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_left ); // added
            imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_left); // added
            Drawable d =new BitmapDrawable(bm_images[picNum]);
            imageSwitcher.setImageDrawable(d);
            System.out.println("Next Pic");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Next Fail " + e);
            imageSwitcher.setImageDrawable(null);
        }
    }

    protected void PreviousPic(){


            picNum--;
            if(picNum < 0)
                picNum = 4;

            tv_counter.setText("" + (picNum+1) + "/5");
        try{    
            imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_right ); // added
            imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_right); // added
            Drawable d =new BitmapDrawable(bm_images[picNum]);
            imageSwitcher.setImageDrawable(d);
            System.out.println("Previous Pic");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Previous Fail " + e);
            //imageSwitcher.setImageResource(R.drawable.download_error);
            imageSwitcher.setImageDrawable(null);
        }

    }

    protected void ChangeBarVisibles(){
        if(topFrame.isShown()){
            topFrame.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bottomFrame.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            topFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bottomFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }


    public View makeView() 
    {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new 
                ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        return imageView;
    }

    class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            try {

                if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                    return false;
                // right to left swipe
                if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    //Toast.makeText(SelectFilterActivity.this, "Left Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    NextPic();
                    //return true;
                }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    //Toast.makeText(SelectFilterActivity.this, "Right Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    PreviousPic();
                    //return true;
                }   
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // nothing
            }
            return true;
        }

       public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e){
           if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                ChangeBarVisibles();
           }
           return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
      setContentView(R.layout.xl_06_photos);

      InitView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        System.gc();
    }
}
```

My results class :

```
public class _02_Results extends ListActivity {

    private SearchParser xmlParser;
    private URLQueryGenerator urlGen;

    //private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private Handler handler;
    private CellAdapter_SearchResults adapter;

    //private Thread thr_downloadImages;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.xl_02_results);

        handler = new Handler();

        //thr_downloadImages = new Thread();

        xmlParser = new SearchParser();
        urlGen = new URLQueryGenerator(getParent());
        adapter =new CellAdapter_SearchResults(_02_Results.this, AppDelegate.properties);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        if(AppDelegate.properties.size() < 1){
            //Reset Results page number to one. Because the results are starting afresh.
            AppDelegate.pageNum = 1;
            handler.post(ReloadCells);
            GetResults();
        }

        if(AppDelegate.results_ListView_State != null)
            getListView().onRestoreInstanceState(AppDelegate.results_ListView_State);

        //if(AppDelegate.pick > 0)
        //  setSelection(AppDelegate.pick);

    }

    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        System.gc();
        new Thread(LoadImages).start();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        //If the last is picked and it is a Get More (Blank/Empty) Cell Download More Properties.
        if(position >= AppDelegate.properties.size()-1 && AppDelegate.properties.get(position).str_ID.length() <= 0)
        {
            xmlParser = new SearchParser();
            LoadMoreResults();
        }

        //Else view Property in Array
        else{
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getParent(), _03_Detailed.class);
            AppDelegate.pick = position;
            TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
            parentActivity.startChildActivity("Detailed_03", myIntent);

            //Save the listview state for later init
            AppDelegate.results_ListView_State = getListView().onSaveInstanceState();
        }
    }


    protected void GetResults(){

        //Show Progress Dialog
        //dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getParent(), "", getResources().getString(R.string.search_alert), true);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.search_alert), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Runnable getResults = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try{
                    //Get XML page from URL generated as a String
                    String xml = XMLfunctions.getXML(urlGen.createSearchURL());

                    if(xml == null){
                        handler.post(DownloadFail_Dialog);
                        System.out.println("xml is null");
                        return;
                    }

                    //Add the parsed properties return from Parser
                    AppDelegate.properties.addAll(xmlParser.ParserXML(xml));// xmlParser.ParserXML(urlString);

                    //Get the number of results for search
                    if(AppDelegate.numResults < 0)
                        AppDelegate.numResults = xmlParser.numResults;

                    System.out.println("Numb of Results:- " + AppDelegate.numResults);

                    //Add blank cell for more button
                    if(AppDelegate.properties.size() < xmlParser.numResults)
                        AppDelegate.properties.add(new Property());

                    //Refresh the ListView
                    try{handler.post(ReloadCells);}
                    catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e);}

                    //dialog.dismiss();
                    if(AppDelegate.properties.size() < 1)
                        handler.post(NoResults_Dialog);
                }
                catch(Exception e){

                    //dialog.dismiss();
                    handler.post(DownloadFail_Dialog);
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
                finally{

                    //Dismiss Progress dialog
                    //dialog.dismiss();
                    System.gc();
                    new Thread(LoadImages).start();
                }
            }
        };
        new Thread(getResults).start();
    }


    protected void LoadMoreResults()
    {
        //Only proceed if more results are available
        if(AppDelegate.numResults > AppDelegate.properties.size()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.search_more), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Show progress dialog
            //dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getParent(), "",  getResources().getString(R.string.loading), true);

            Runnable getResults = new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    try{
                        AppDelegate.pageNum++;
                        String xml = null;

                        //Get XML Page as a String
                        xml = XMLfunctions.getXML(urlGen.createSearchURL() +  "&Page=" + AppDelegate.pageNum);
                        if(xml == null){
                            handler.post(DownloadFail_Dialog);
                            System.out.println("xml is null");
                            return;
                        }

                        //Add properties returned from XML Parser
                        AppDelegate.properties.addAll(AppDelegate.properties.size()-1, xmlParser.ParserXML(xml));// xmlParser.ParserXML(urlString);
                        handler.post(ReloadCells);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println(e);
                        AppDelegate.pageNum--;
                        //dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    finally{
                        //dialog.dismiss();
                        System.gc();
                        /*
                        if(thr_downloadImages.isAlive()){
                            thr_downloadImages.stop();
                            thr_downloadImages = null;
                        }   
                        thr_downloadImages = new Thread(LoadImages);
                        thr_downloadImages.start();
                        */
                        new Thread(LoadImages).start();
                    }
                }
            };
            new Thread(getResults).start();
        }
        else{
            handler.post(NoResults_Dialog);
        }
    }

    /**
     *  **IMPORTANT**
     * 
     *  The functions below are for the activity to be accessed at any point.
     *  They should only be access by Handler.
     * 
     *  By using the handler, this can be accessed from inside a separate Thread other than the Main one.
     *  This is done because some GUI elements can not be accessed inside a Thread, other than the Main.
     *  
     */

    private final Runnable LoadImages = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            for(int x=0; x <AppDelegate.properties.size(); x++){
                try{    
                    //Run the image download twice, because sometimes the images doesn't download the first time
                    if(AppDelegate.properties.get(x).img_thumb == null)
                        AppDelegate.properties.get(x).img_thumb = FindPropertyActivity.DownloadImage(AppDelegate.properties.get(x).str_imgURL1);
                    if(AppDelegate.properties.get(x).img_thumb == null)
                        AppDelegate.properties.get(x).img_thumb = FindPropertyActivity.DownloadImage(AppDelegate.properties.get(x).str_imgURL1);

                    handler.post(ReloadCells);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e.toString());}
            }
        }
    };

    private final Runnable ReloadCells = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            adapter.UpdateDataSet(AppDelegate.properties);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    private final Runnable DownloadFail_Dialog = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent());
            builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.download_fail))
                   .setCancelable(false)
                   .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //do nothing
                       }
                   });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    };

    private final Runnable NoResults_Dialog = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent());
            builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.no_results))
                   .setCancelable(false)
                   .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //do nothing
                       }
                   });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    };
}
```

I dont have any more room to paste another class :(

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance!!

here is the log cat for the loading searches

> 09-11 13:13:47.451: I/System.out(8774): Parser Completed!! 09-11
>   13:13:52.541: I/System.out(8774): java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   http://images.ultrait.me/ImageProcessor.aspx?imageURL=381/Sales/321464/53674_T_ADDRESSES_52056_TN.jpg&Text=LET
>   AGREED 09-11 13:13:53.431: I/System.out(8774):
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   http://images.ultrait.me/ImageProcessor.aspx?imageURL=381/Sales/321465/58467_T_ADDRESSES_57077_OT.jpg&Text=LET
>   AGREED 09-11 13:13:54.031: I/System.out(8774):
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   http://images.ultrait.me/ImageProcessor.aspx?imageURL=381/Sales/321466/58441_T_ADDRESSES_57075_OT.jpg&Text=LET
>   AGREED 09-11 13:13:54.651: I/System.out(8774):
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   http://images.ultrait.me/ImageProcessor.aspx?imageURL=381/Sales/321467/53631_T_ADDRESSES_52035_TN.jpg&Text=LET
>   AGREED 09-11 13:13:55.801: I/System.out(8774):
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   http://images.ultrait.me/ImageProcessor.aspx?imageURL=381/Sales/321468/53626_T_ADDRESSES_52026_TN.jpg&Text=LET
>   AGREED 09-11 13:13:59.591: I/System.out(8774):
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   http://images.ultrait.me/ImageProcessor.aspx?imageURL=381/Sales/321469/53540_T_ADDRESSES_51961_TN.jpg&Text=LET
>   AGREED 09-11 13:14:00.001: D/PowerManagerService(182): acquireWakeLock
>   flags=0x1 tag=AlarmManager 09-11 13:14:00.031:
>   D/PowerManagerService(182): releaseWakeLock flags=0x1 tag=AlarmManager
>   09-11 13:14:02.051: I/System.out(8774): java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   http://images.ultrait.me/ImageProcessor.aspx?imageURL=381/Sales/321470/53659_T_ADDRESSES_52050_TN.jpg&Text=LET
>   AGREED 09-11 13:14:03.691: I/System.out(8774):
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   http://images.ultrait.me/ImageProcessor.aspx?imageURL=381/Sales/321471/53611_T_ADDRESSES_52018_TN.jpg&Text=LET
>   AGREED 09-11 13:14:04.761: I/System.out(8774):
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   http://images.ultrait.me/ImageProcessor.aspx?imageURL=381/Sales/321472/53589_T_ADDRESSES_51972_TN.jpg&Text=LET
>   AGREED 09-11 13:14:05.531: I/System.out(8774):
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   http://images.ultrait.me/ImageProcessor.aspx?imageURL=381/Sales/321473/46397_T_ADDRESSES_43205_OT.jpg&Text=LET
>   AGREED 09-11 13:14:05.851: I/System.out(8774):
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   http://images.ultrait.me/ImageProcessor.aspx?imageURL=381/Sales/321474/53664_T_ADDRESSES_52053_TN.jpg&Text=LET
>   AGREED 09-11 13:14:06.531: I/System.out(8774):
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   http://images.ultrait.me/ImageProcessor.aspx?imageURL=381/Sales/321475/53669_T_ADDRESSES_52054_TN.jpg&Text=LET
>   AGREED 09-11 13:14:08.701: I/System.out(8774):
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   http://images.ultrait.me/ImageProcessor.aspx?imageURL=381/Sales/321476/53651_T_ADDRESSES_52049_TN.jpg&Text=LET
>   AGREED 09-11 13:14:09.991: I/System.out(8774):
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   http://images.ultrait.me/ImageProcessor.aspx?imageURL=381/Sales/321477/43296_T_ADDRESSES_40850_TN.jpg&Text=LET
>   AGREED 09-11 13:14:11.331: I/System.out(8774):
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   http://images.ultrait.me/ImageProcessor.aspx?imageURL=381/Sales/321478/53944_T_ADDRESSES_52241_TN.jpg&Text=LET
>   AGREED 09-11 13:14:11.961: I/System.out(8774): Numb of Results:- 177
>   09-11 13:14:12.031: I/System.out(8774):
>   java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found:  09-11
>   13:14:12.031: I/System.out(8774): java.lang.NullPointerException 09-11
>   13:14:12.031: I/System.out(8774): java.net.MalformedURLException:
>   Protocol not found:  09-11 13:14:12.031: I/System.out(8774):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 09-11 13:14:12.181: I/pcm_service(107):
>   process rmnet event 09-11 13:14:12.181: I/pcm_service(107):  rstate ==
>   PCM_RMNETSTATE_ERROR in pcm_monitor_kevents 09-11 13:14:12.181:
>   I/dun_service(115): process rmnet event 09-11 13:14:12.181:
>   I/dun_service(115): Post event 3 09-11 13:14:12.191:
>   I/dun_service(115): received event: DUN_EVENT_RMNET_DOWN  09-11
>   13:14:12.191: I/dun_service(115): received event(DUN_EVENT_RMNET_DOWN)
>   in state(DUN_STATE_USB_UNPLUG) 09-11 13:14:12.191: I/dun_service(115):
>   Ignoring the event DUN_EVENT_RMNET_DOWN in USB_UNPLUG_STATE 09-11
>   13:14:12.191: I/dun_service(115): Moved to state(DUN_STATE_USB_UNPLUG)

Comment: where exactly is the exception coming from?

Comment: paste the whole logcat log

Comment: You have ``http://images.ultrait.me/ImageProcessor.aspx?imageURL=381/Sales/321470/53659_T_ADDRESSES_52050_TN.jpg&Text=LET AGREED`` as your link (space in between LET and AGREED) but the actual link doesn't include the ``AGREED`` i.e. the link is just ``http://images.ultrait.me/ImageProcessor.aspx?imageURL=381/Sales/321470/53659_T_ADDRESSES_52050_TN.jpg&Text=LET``. This probably isn't the reason as it is only a URL paramater but just in case

Comment: @Metalhead1247 i have pasted my Log cat result

Comment: http://craftingjava.blogspot.in/2012/05/file-not-found-exception-file-not-found.html

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked your code but the first thing that comes in my mind is : Have you checked the permissions of the application ?
It may come from there. (E.G. : No internet permission, file not found because it doesn't have the right to acces to it)

Edit : You should check (debug or log) if this "str_imageURLs[i]" does not return something strange (And you should get rid of the spaces in your URL).

Then, if there is a problem, I guess it comes from this : "FindPropertyActivity.DownloadImage"
Could you post it ?
Do you get the image as an input stream and form a drawable from it (if it is not what is done in DownloadImage) ?

**Edit2** : I created a basic application with just an ImageView in a layout. Then I used your "DownloadImage" method to get the image from the url without its additionnal parameters (I stopped at ".jg"). It doesn't work on android 4.2 because it requires it to be asynchronous.

I added this in my main activity and then it worked :

```
ThreadPolicy tp = ThreadPolicy.LAX;
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);
```

But clearly, this is not something to be done.

The matter is neither your URL or your method to get the image. It work just fine with android 4.2.

Could you replace all your system.out.println*** by a Log.e("PutClassNameHere", "Put your cutom message there", throwable); ?
This will write the error in your logCat

Comment: public static Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL){
  Bitmap bmImg = null;
  URL myFileUrl =null;
  
  try {
   myFileUrl= new URL(URL);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   
   System.out.println(e);
  }
  try {
   HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
   conn.setDoInput(true);
   conn.connect();
   InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
   BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
   options.inSampleSize = 3;
   bmImg=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options);
   

  }
  catch(Exception e){
   System.out.println(e);
  }
  return bmImg;
 }

Comment: Sorry its the only way that i could post it. Sorry i only just see that you had edited your comment.

Comment: I need to make the bitmap smaller as its running out of memory also but again i dont know how to do this? :(

Comment: What version of android are you working on ?
I'll try to execute your code on the same version to see what's wrong.

Comment: I'm not 100% but i think that it is 2.2 as thats what i have in my src code

Comment: ok, you should replace all your system.out by a Log.e as written above. This will show clearly the error in the logCat (and normally its location).

Comment: Ahh ok, I will give that a go. Once i know where the error actually is it will help.

Comment: Log are very usefull for debuging purposes. Take a look at [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)
You should use the log instead of system.out so that it appears in the logCat.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Have you found your answer ?

Comment: has the logcat evolved since you replaced all the "system.out" ?
Perhaps could you update the traces you posted